# trying to use a nested Instr function in Isnumeric

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a program in VBA for excel that will search through a column of "names", and if that name has the case-sensitive string "CAN" within it, then the column 6 columns over will be added to a total (canadaTotal). This is what I have so far... The problem is within the instr/isnumeric portion. I'm sure I'm using one of them incorrectly.. and if anybody could offer an alternative solution, or a quick fix, I would appreciate it.

(hint... I'm not sure if i can use my "search" variable as the second input of the instr function...)

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim canadaTotal As Integer
Dim search As String
Dim canadaCheck As Long
i = 1
col = 4
canadaTotal = 0

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

While Not Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, col).Value = ""
search = Cells(i, col).Value

If IsNumeric(InStr(0, search, "CAN")) Then


canadaTotal = canadaTotal + Cells(i, col).Offset(0, 6).Value

End If

i = i + 1

Wend
MsgBox (canadaTotal)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the Instr function starts with position 1, not position 0.

Also, Instr returns 0 if the string is not found, not a non-numeric value, so your test will always be true.

Additionally, the default for Instr is that it will not search case sensitive.  In order to search case sensitive, you need to use the last "compare" parameter and set it to vbBinaryCompare.

Change this to:

```
 If Instr(1, search, "CAN", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
```

and it should work.